# jQuery table search all columns when enter

Tags: jquery, search, html-table

Hi I have a Jquery Table Search and My requirement is to when click enter to search all the table columns... Right now I can Search only two columns... Can someone please help me to bind the rest so that when click enter the entire table will search.

SO basically when some one hits enter I need search by, Name, Email, Phone, Price

Your help is appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Table search on enter</title> 

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>            

    <style>
        td,tr, th{
            padding:15px;
        }        
    </style>
      
    
</head>

<body>

    <input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Filtrer" /> 
    
    <a class="button"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Report Error</a>
               
    <br />
    
        <section class="table-box">
  <table class="order-table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Phone</th>
     <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Williams</td>
     <td>williams@ooutlook.com</td>
     <td>644</td>
     <td>56453454</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Amber Samuels</td>
     <td>amber@james.com</td>
     <td>64345</td>
     <td>734534</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Rehen</td>
     <td>rehen@gmail.com</td>
     <td>634534</td>
     <td>5345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Alfred fedric</td>
     <td>fedric@gmail.com</td>
     <td>634534</td>
     <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Taylor</td>
     <td>taylor@gmail.com</td>
     <td>0978098</td>
     <td>896899</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Classis</td>
     <td>classic@fgf.com</td>
     <td>634534</td>
     <td>45345</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </section>
    
    
    <script>
       // Can search only two columns I want to search all columns
    var currentMonth;
    var nameRowIndex = 0; // O is first column Name
    var emailRowIndex = 1; // 1 is Second column Email    
    
    $('.light-table-filter').change(function(){
       //The Event for Month change. 
       currentMonth =  $('.light-table-filter').val();
       changeData();
    });

    function changeData(){ 
            var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('order-table');//Table Name goes here..
            [].forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
                    [].forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {

                            [].forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);

                    });
            });
    }
    
    function _filter(row) {
    console.log("row: " + row.cells[nameRowIndex,emailRowIndex].textContent);
            var text = row.cells[nameRowIndex,emailRowIndex].textContent.toLowerCase(), val = currentMonth;
            row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    } 
    </script>    
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of your jquery use below code it will works for all column

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".light-table-filter").keypress(function (e) {
  var key = e.which;
   if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
  {    
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".order-table tbody tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });  
  }
  });
});
```

```js
// Can search only two columns I want to search all columns
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".light-table-filter").keypress(function (e) {
  var key = e.which;
   if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
  {    
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".order-table tbody tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });  
  }
  });
});


/*var currentMonth;
var nameRowIndex = 0; // O is first column Name
var emailRowIndex = 1; // 1 is Second column Email
var phoneRowIndex = 2;
var priceRowIndex = 3;

$('.light-table-filter').change(function(){
   //The Event for Month change. 
   currentMonth =  $('.light-table-filter').val();
   changeData();
});

function changeData(){ 
        var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('order-table');//Table Name goes here..
        [].forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
                [].forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {

                        [].forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);

                });
        });
}

function _filter(row) {
        var text = row.cells[nameRowIndex,emailRowIndex,phoneRowIndex,priceRowIndex].textContent.toLowerCase(), val = currentMonth;
        row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
}*/
```

```css
   td,tr, th{
        padding:15px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Filtrer" /> 

<a class="button"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Report Error</a>

<br />

    <section class="table-box">
    <table class="order-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Williams</td>
                <td>williams@ooutlook.com</td>
                <td>644</td>
                <td>56453454</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amber Samuels</td>
                <td>amber@james.com</td>
                <td>64345</td>
                <td>734534</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rehen</td>
                <td>rehen@gmail.com</td>
                <td>634534</td>
                <td>5345</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfred fedric</td>
                <td>fedric@gmail.com</td>
                <td>634534</td>
                <td>123123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Taylor</td>
                <td>taylor@gmail.com</td>
                <td>0978098</td>
                <td>896899</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Classis</td>
                <td>classic@fgf.com</td>
                <td>634534</td>
                <td>45345</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Savior!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Savior!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much. Thanks alot. Now all the table fields are searching without a Error. Thank you so much. Appreciate your Time taken to resolve this,.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you just want to be able to search at any stage of being on the page, not just in an input or on focus of something else.

Using jQuery you can do the following

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.charCode == 13){ //charCode 13 is the enter key
    doSearch();
  }
});
```

If you just want to be able to search whilst you are focused on the search input you can do the following

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.charCode == 13 && $(".light-table-filter").is(":focus")){
    doSearch();
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but this is all okay... Its just the present code is not searching all the table columns... thats all.

Comment: Oh no worries, I can help with that too, however, others have already

Comment: In that case then, after work I will write out a solution, stay tuned for the next 8 hours  :)

Answer (score 0):

Update filters method, add indexes of fields you need to be searched

```
var text = row.cells[nameRowIndex,emailRowIndex,2,3].textContent.toLowerCase(), val = currentMonth;
row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
```

Comment: Nothing works I want to seatch all columns... Please help